# ETL to import data into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, etl

I would like to know about an ETL tool to upload data into a MongoDB, I've tried with Pentaho and Talend, but I would prefer something a bit lighter, because my process is so simple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a JSON file 'test.json' (and also assume it is valid JSON) you can use command line program `mongoimport`.

Example:

```
mongoimport --host localhost:27017 --db test --collection test --username johndoe --password my secret --authenticationDatabase admin  --file test.json
```